# Form submit button is redirecting instead of submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to customize a Google form with css and js and am running into a roadblock. When I get to the end of the form and submit, instead of submitting, it automatically redirects to the google form with the info filled out where I then need to hit submit on the google form.

What is causing the form to redirect instead of submitting from my site?

```
<form id="regForm" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSf3i00Wf9q9k-g8fFlvIEtBIOApiKKpCJwzuIqqKo5ig29ekQ/formResponse"  method="POST" >
  <h1 style="color:white; font-size: 40px;"></h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab" style="color:white; font-size: 40px;">1 Let's start with your email:
    <p><input placeholder="Type your email here" oninput="this.className = ''" name="emailAddress"  value=""></p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab" style="color:white; font-size: 40px;">3 What locations are you open to?
<br>
<br>
<label class="checks" >Miami
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="Miami">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="checks" >Fort Lauderdale
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="Fort Lauderdale">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="checks" >West Palm Beach
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="West Palm Beach">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <br>
  </div>
 <div class="tab" style="color:white; font-size: 40px;">4 What firm size/s are you open to?
<br>
<br>
<label class="checks">All
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value=All">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="checks">Boutique
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Boutique">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="checks">Mid
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Mid">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="checks">Large
  <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Large">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  <br>
  </div>


  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";


  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Your form needs a submit button inside of it. When you click the submit button, the form will 'post' to the 'action' specified in the form's action endpoint. I do not see a submit button in your form.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see anything in your code that would prevent the default form event. So when you hit submit, the form is being submitted. Your example code also does not seem to contain everything, I do not see where your submit callback is at all.

Comment: You also have a HTML Syntax issue here: `<input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value=All">` missing a `"`

Comment: Thank you for your help @Twisty. I just added the " to All. Unfortunately, I'm a complete beginner with JS and copied the multi-step-form from W3schools and make some tweaks. The next button turns into a submit button at the end so I can't use a standard HTML <button type="submit " line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you validate the form upon each step. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)

  function showTab(n) {
    var x = $(".tab");
    x.hide();
    x.eq(n).show();
    if (n == 0) {
      $("#prevBtn").hide();
    } else {
      $("prevBtn").css("display", "inline");
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
      $("#nextBtn").html("Submit");
    } else {
      $("nextBtn").html("Next");
    }
    fixStepIndicator(n);
  }

  function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = $(".tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    if (currentTab > 0 && currentTab < x.length) {
      $("#prevBtn").show();
    }
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
      // ... the form gets submitted:
      $("#regForm").submit();
      return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
  }

  function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x = $(".tab"),
      y = $("input", x),
      valid = true;
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    y.each(function(i, el) {
      // If a field is empty...
      if ($(el).is("[type='email']") && $(el).val() == "") {
        // add an "invalid" class to the field:
        $(el).addClass("invalid");
        // and set the current valid status to false
        valid = false;
      }
    });
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
      $(".step").eq(currentTab).addClass("finish");
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
  }

  function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var x = $(".step");
    x.removeClass("active");
    x.eq(currentTab).addClass("active");
  }

  function mark(ev) {
    var self = $(ev.target);
    var chkd = $("[type='checkbox']", self).prop("checked");
    if (!chkd) {
      $(".check", self).addClass("marked");
      $("[type='checkbox']", self).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(".check", self).removeClass("marked");
      $("[type='checkbox']", self).prop("checked", false);
    }
  }

  showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

  $("#prevBtn, #nextBtn").click(function() {
    nextPrev($(this).attr("id") == "prevBtn" ? -1 : 1);
  });

  $(".tab ul li").click(mark);

  /*
  $("#regForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return validateForm();
  });
  */
});
```

```css
form {
  background-color: #ccf;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.all-tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: none;
}

.tab ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
}

.tab .check {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  margin: 2px;
}

.tab ul li .check.marked {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tab ul li input {
  display: none;
}

.step {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.step.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="regForm" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/1FAIpQLSf3i00Wf9q9k-g8fFlvIEtBIOApiKKpCJwzuIqqKo5ig29ekQ/formResponse" method="POST">
  <ol class="all-tabs">
    <li class="tab">1. Let's start with your email <input type="email" placeholder="Type your email here" name="emailAddress" />
    </li>
    <li class="tab">2. What locations are you open to?
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>Miami</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="Miami">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Fort Lauderdale</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="Fort Lauderdale">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>West Palm Beach</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.954260955" value="West Palm Beach">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">3. What firm size/s are you open to?
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="checks">All</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="All">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="checks">Boutique</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Boutique">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="checks">Mid</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Mid">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="checks">Large</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="entry.2006485092" value="Large">
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Added an example of how you could check the form before submitting it.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty! I just figured it out! Apparently the code was fine. The problem was with the settings in my Google Form. I had it set to only one response a person which meant you had to sign in before submitting. When I unchecked that, the problem went away and it's now submitting just fine. Thank you again for taking the time to help!